# Django Transforming to Raw Query

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am working on a django project and I must not use django's get method for getting data from datbase. I could not understand how can I make this query in sqlite.

```
obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=1)
```

In general where can I learn this queries SQL equivalents?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mymodel WHERE id=1`? Exactly why you don't use the Django ORM?

Comment: It is a requirement in assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, Querysets have a [query attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet) containing the query to be executed.You can use like that:

```
print(YourModel.objects.filter(field=field_value).query)
```

if you implement `get_object_or_404` to raw sql query, you can use select command and check sql results count.If there is no result, you can raise 404 exception:

```
your_obj = YourModel.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM your_model where pk= %s',[your_pk]):
if not your_obj:
    raise Http404
```